# How to put scores into entity names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If some player has a score of `S` in objective `O`, how can I summon an armor stand with the name `Score: S`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do so directly. You will instead need to have separate commands for each and every possible score. For larger amounts this would not be feasible:

```
/execute @a[score_OBJ_min=1,score_OBJ=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Score: 1"}
/execute @a[score_OBJ_min=2,score_OBJ=2] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Score: 2"}
/execute @a[score_OBJ_min=3,score_OBJ=3] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Score: 3"}
```